# Can someone explain this potential variable expansion issue when running smartctl from script vs directly in terminal?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, variable-substitution

I am trying to write a script that collects some info about disk health as a part of customising ShredOS. I cannot understand what is wrong with the following snippet.

```
    #get disk info
    disk_info=$(lsblk --path -AdJo NAME,SIZE,ROTA)

    #get names of disks
    disk_names+=($(jq '.blockdevices[] | .name' <<< "$disk_info"))

    printf "\n\n# DISK HEALTH REPORTS #\n\n"
    for name in ${disk_names[@]};
      do
              #this command works in shell but cannot find device type when run through the script.
              disk_health=$(sudo smartctl -s on -a "$name")
              printf "$disk_health"
      done
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
"/dev/nvme0n1": Unable to detect device type
Pleas specify device type with the -d option.
```

But when I run the command `sudo smartctl -s on -a /dev/nvme0n1` in the shell, I get the desired output. I also get the desired output if I substitute `$name` with `/dev/nvme0n1` in the script (albeit with a warning `printf:106: %\n: invalid directive` on the line number (106) corresponding to `printf "$disk_health"`

I've tried to echo `$name` and it displays the disk name with its path correctly. I have also tried replacing `$name` with `"$name"` and `echo $name` (between backticks) but with the same output.

I'm running the script with zsh on Debian bookworm.

Comment: in `printf "$disk_health"`, you're putting the whole output of `smartctl` in the format string of `printf`, to be interpreted for format specifiers like `%s`. That's probably not what you want, and in a C program, that would open up huge issues with stray memory accesses. Here, you get away with just the error message. If you want to just print the string as-is, give `printf` the appropriate format string, i.e. `printf %s "$disk_health"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON processing preserves the double quotes, which are passed as-is to `smartctl`. You need to remove them with `jq`’s `-r` option:

```
disk_names+=($(jq -r '.blockdevices[] | .name' <<< "$disk_info"))
```